# New-Item returns WriteError: FileNotFound Exception

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

Still pretty new to powershell so maybe this is an easy fix. I am running powershell as administrator so I *should* be able to do what I want-however I can't for the life of me figure out this issue. It doesn't make any sense why creating a new file would raise a `'FileNotFound'` error...I'm trying to make a freaking file of course it isn't there yet!

I am using powershell 5.1.18362.1171

```
PS C:\Users\<myname>\OneDrive - <othername>\Documents\transport\d3 stuff> New-Item -name testfile1.txt -ItemType file  -force          
New-Item : Could not find file 'C:\Users\<myname>\OneDrive - <othername>\Documents\transport\d3 stuff\testfile1.txt'.
    At line:1 char:1
    + New-Item  -name testfile1.txt -ItemType file  -force
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Users\M31252...f\testfile1.txt:String) [New-Item], FileNotFoundException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NewItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand
```

However I can create a file in other directories, maybe it has something to do with path expansion since I was trying to make a file in a path with spaces?

```
PS C:\Users\m31252> New-Item -Path . -Name "testfile1.txt" -ItemType "file" -Value "text string"


    Directory: C:\Users\m31252


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----         4/8/2021   2:25 PM             11 testfile1.txt
```

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you running?

Comment: `New-Item -Path . -Name "testfile1.txt" -ItemType "file" -Value "This is a text string."`

Comment: @DavidPostill 5.1.18362.1171

Comment: that error usually means that you have a permission problem OR that your file name has something "odd" about it - iffy characters like `[]`, for instance. what happens if you build the full path for the file and use that with your `New-Item` call?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I tried `New-Item -Path 'C:\Users\<myname>\OneDrive - <othername>\Documents\transport' -Name 'newfile.txt' -ItemType "file" -Value "text string"` and got the same error. Maybe it is a permissions issue, then? This is a company machine but I have changed `ExecutionPolicy` for `CurrentUser` to `Unrestricted`. I'm not sure what other permissions I could edit.

Comment: I'm beginning to think there may be issue trying to access the "OneDrive" space from within powershell...

Comment: yep ... it looks like a permission problem. you will need to dig into that. good luck! [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be a permissions error:

```
PS C:\Users\<myname>> (get-acl '.\OneDrive - <othername>\learning d3\').Access


FileSystemRights  : DeleteSubdirectoriesAndFiles
AccessControlType : Deny
IdentityReference : Everyone
IsInherited       : True
InheritanceFlags  : ContainerInherit
PropagationFlags  : None

FileSystemRights  : FullControl
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
IsInherited       : True
InheritanceFlags  : ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit
PropagationFlags  : None

FileSystemRights  : FullControl
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : BUILTIN\Administrators
IsInherited       : True
InheritanceFlags  : ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit
PropagationFlags  : None

FileSystemRights  : FullControl
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : <thirdname>
IsInherited       : True
InheritanceFlags  : ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit
PropagationFlags  : None



PS C:\Users\<myname>> (get-acl '.\OneDrive - <othername>\Documents\').Access


FileSystemRights  : FullControl
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
IsInherited       : False
InheritanceFlags  : ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit
PropagationFlags  : None

FileSystemRights  : FullControl
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : <thirdname>
IsInherited       : False
InheritanceFlags  : ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit
PropagationFlags  : None
```

When trying to change the ACL of the problem dir I get an `UnauthorizedAccessException` which supports this idea. Now to figure out how I am gonna get rights to change this ACL...